# A deduction in Hoffman Kunze whose explanation is not given

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am self studying linear Algebra from Hoffman and Kunze and Couldn't think about how a deduction mist be true.

On page 15 authors wrote

[image]

> Why if a solution $x_{1}$ ,..., $x_{n}$ belongs to F then the system of equations must have a solution with $x_{1} $,...,$x_{n}$ in $F_{1} $ ?

Is it is due to the fact that in AX=Y, both A and Y are belonging to $ F_{1}$ .so solution X must exist in $ F_{1} $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the augmented matrix $[A|Y]$ has the same row-reduced echelon form in $F_1$ and $F$.